# How to get key and values of particular of jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have one jqGrid like below(part of the code)

```
    $(function() {
        options = $("#pdbconfiggrid").jqGrid({
            url:URL,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
           colNames:['Display Name','Property Name', 'Property Value', 'Group Type'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'display_name',index:'key',editable:false,sortable:false, width:30},
                {name:'key',index:'_key', hidden:true},
                {name:'value',index:'value', editable:false,sortable:false, width:100, formatter:returnPropertyValue},
                {name:'group',index:'group',sortable:false, hidden:true, width:30},
            ],
            postData: {},
            rowNum: -1,
            height: 'auto',
            headertitles:true,
            autowidth: true,
            viewrecords: false,
            toppager: false,
            emptyrecords: "Empty records",
            cmTemplate: { title: false},
            loadonce: false,
            altRows: true,
            sortname: 'index',
            sortorder: "asc",
            grouping:true,
            groupingView : { 
                groupField : ['group'],
                groupColumnShow : [false],
                groupCollapse : true,
                groupSorted: false,
                groupDataSorted: false
            },
```

I am setting multiple group values(like A,B,C,D) for this grid. 
Now , how can i get all key & values of particular group on given grop name
like  jqGrid.getGroupData("A");

thanks

Comment: Why have you tagged this with [java]? And what's the `options` variable for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried like this. and it works

```
  function getGroupData(group_name) {
var rowData;
var complete_data = jQuery("#syncconfiggrid").jqGrid('getRowData');
var group_data = {};
for (var index in complete_data) {
    rowData = complete_data[index];
    if (group_name == rowData.group) {
        var prop_key = rowData.key;
        if (null != prop_key && prop_key.length > 2)
            group_data[prop_key] = $('#' + prop_key.replaceAll(".", "_")).val(); // this is my code specific
    }
}
return group_data;
}
```